# Does Paho MQTT Asynchronous C Client Buffer Received Messages?

Tags: c, paho

I've been reading the documentation for the Paho Asynchronous MQTT library https://eclipse.github.io/paho.mqtt.c/MQTTAsync/html/index.html and it's not really clear to me if blocking for too long in the defined MQTTAsync_messageArrived callback will cause messages to get missed or if they are buffered on another thread.

All it says on this page (https://eclipse.github.io/paho.mqtt.c/MQTTAsync/html/async.html) is that "Processing of handshaking and maintaining the network connection is performed in the background". This makes it sound like it's able to maintain the connection to the broker but it's not clear if that also includes reception of topics.

I see there is a value in MQTTAsync_createOptions for max buffered messages, but from what I can understand this is a buffer for messages getting published, not received. Or is it both?

Am I safe to potentially block in this message arrived callback or do I need to utilize some sort of producer/consuming queue on my own thread so no messages get missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library contains a single thread for reading the incoming packets from the socket and calls `messageArrived()` from that thread. So if you block that thread, you are blocking all input processing. So don't block that thread for long.

If you want to buffer incoming messages, it's best to write them to a thread-safe queue to be consumed by your application when time permits.

And your suspicion is correct. `maxBufferedMessages` is for out-bound (publishing) traffic. It allows your application to "publish" messages while disconnected from the broker. Those will be held in a FIFO and automatically sent, in order, when the connection is re-established.

The doc comment on that one is not clear enough. It could stand to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You should never run blocking long running tasks in the `messageArrived` callback. If you have long running tasks you should hand these off to a separate thread